# Replace a part of url with htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

I have a part of url to replace with htaccess :

How to replace `root/aaa/bbb/css/images/ddd.image.png` to `root/aaa/css/images/ddd.image.png`

I tried without success this code in the .htaccess in the root folder :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aaa/bbb/(.*) /aaa/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

In the aaa folder, there is this .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: @anubhava the htaccess is located in the root folder

Comment: Q1. Is there any other .htaccess in your system? Q2. Are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava you are right, there is another .htaccess file! I have rewritten the question including this parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this rule in `/aaa/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /aaa/

RewriteRule ^bbb/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not working. I always get 404 error for my images,

Comment: When you get 404 what URL do you see in your browser?

Comment: Your previous comments make me reconsider the way to access my pictures. Therefore, I have updated the code instead modify the htaccess. I mark the subject close even if this answer is not working for me. Up to you to delete your answer if you want.